# Get function results using named pipes (python)

Tags: python

I have one dictionary (inverted_index) that maps integer keys to list values all follows:

```
key          value
101332      1011772  10841334  21363790
101334      1142902
101347      764543
```

I'm trying to use named pipes so that the user can input a key and then the result will be the list of values. However, I'm not getting any result.

The following is the code I tried:

```
import os
import errno

def getDocuments(inp):
    return [inverted_index[x] for x in inp]

FIFO = 'dictpipe'

try:
    os.mkfifo(FIFO)
except OSError as oe:
    if oe.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise

print("Opening FIFO...")
with open(FIFO) as fifo:
    print("FIFO opened")
    data = set()
    while True:
        data = fifo.read()
        if len(data) == 0:
            print("Writer closed")
            break
        dd = getDocuments(data)
        print(dd)
```

The following is the result I'm getting:

```
Terminal 1:  $ python dictpipes.py 
             Opening FIFO...

Terminal 2:  $ echo 101332 | bc > dictpipe

Terminal 1:  $ python dictpipes.py 
             Opening FIFO... 
             FIFO opened 
             [[], [], [], [], [], [], []] 
             Writer closed
```

As you can see I'm getting a list of empty lists.. the result should be: 
[1011772, 10841335, 21363790]

**Edit:** 
The code used to create the dictionary..

```
from collections import defaultdict

inverted_index = defaultdict(list)  #inverted index dictionary
forward_index = defaultdict(list) #forward index dictionary

with open('term_dict.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        items = line.split()
        term, doc = items[0], items[1:]
        for doc in items[1:]:
            inverted_index[term].append(doc)
            forward_index[doc].append(term)
```

Comment: Can you show the content of `inverted_index` as it is actually stored? Is it e.g. `{101332: [1011772, 10841334, 21363790]...}`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting input as a string and `for x in inp` in `getDocuments` iterates through the characters of the string. It finds no values in the dicationary corresponding to "1", "0", "1", "3", "3", or "2" so returns a list of empty lists. Instead (assuming keys are stored as integers in your dictionary), try:

```
def getDocuments(inp):
    return inverted_index[int(inp)]
```

Or, if you want the user to be able to enter more than one key, separated by spaces, you can do this by splitting the input:

```
def getDocuments(inp)
    return [inverted_index[int(x)] for x in inp.split()]
```

**EDIT**

As your dictionary is built from a text file, the keys must be strings. So you  just need to strip any whitespace (including the newline character "\n") from the user's input before doing the look-up.

```
   return inverted_index[inp.strip()]
```

Alternatively build your dictionary with integers instead of strings, and use the first `getDocuments` function above.

```
with open('term_dict.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        items = line.split()
        term = int(items[0])
        for doc in items[1:]:
            doc_int = int(doc)
            inverted_index[term].append(doc_int)
            forward_index[doc_int].append(term)
```

Comment: I tried these and it still gives an empty list :( I tried to print what the user enters and it shows this "101332\n", I don't know where "\n" comes from, maybe this is what's causing the problem! @Stuart

Comment: what form is your `inverted_index` dictionary in?

Comment: what do you mean by the form? it is sorted! the keys are sorted numbers! 
keys are integers and values are lists! @Stuart

Comment: Does `print(inverted_index[101332])` produce the expected result? See slight edit to my first suggestion. "\n" is a line break, but `int` should ignore this when converting the string to an integer.

Comment: Yes it does, it gives the right result! only when I try it with the pipe it gives an empty list and I cannot figure out why! @Stuart

Comment: I can only suggest debugging by inserting some more print statements. Presumably there is still some mismatch between `data` and the dictionary key. A regular dictionary would raise a key error rather than returning an empty list, so you must be using something like a `defaultdict`? Can you insert the code used to create the dictionary in your  question?

Comment: I have edited the post by adding the code I used to create the dictionary, there are actually two dictionaries, but right now I just want one to work with the named pipes. @Stuart

Comment: See edit. Your dictionary has strings as keys, not integers.